# Gameobject instance in vertical layout shows different in some phones

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

i make a game on unity and i am having problems in some devices.

the row of the vertical layout are Gameobject instances, but it shows bad in samsung and motorola [wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trV47.jpg) on xiaomi shows just like this [good](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDgVs.jpg)

i tried to change  the values of the properties of the scroll view but i couldnt make it work

Answer (score 1):

For each of the UI Text element under Nombre ('Name'), you have to set RectTransform's Anchor values. I suppose you are generating the text elements through code. In that case you have to change the attribute while instantiating. Let me know if you need help, I will edit my answer.

Comment: thanks, i could make it work adding gameobject.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1,1,1) to the Gameobject instance

Comment: @GonzaloDanielCiano you are welcome, please mark the question answered if the answer was helpful.